# Android : Custom Shapes (Behaviour of layer-list)

Tags: android, android-layout, shapes

I am using a layer list to create a shape which has only 1dp border at the bottom .

I wrote an xml for creating the shape

```
<!-- Bottom Line -->

<item>

    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid android:color="#CCCCCC" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:bottom="1dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="@color/gradient_end"
            android:startColor="@color/gradient_start" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

This works perfectly in all phones except phones with small screen size. In small screen sizes the border doesn't show up . Is this some kind of bug in android  or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Values of colors  :                                              <color name="gradient_start">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="gradient_end">#EEEEEE</color>

Comment: Not really an answer, but just thought I should point out that drawing a line using this approach is rather expensive in terms of [overdraw](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/01/android-performance-case-study/). You'll potentially end up drawing large areas more than once just to visualize a single horizontal line.

Comment: Absoultely correct MH . Can you suggest some other approach to achieve the same effect ?

Comment: The most straightforward approach would be to create a 9-patch for the different density ratios; only fill the line colour and leave all other pixels transparent. You can have this 9-patch incude the gradient, but more flexible is to use it in a `LayerDrawable` as above. Another option, which I haven't actually tried myself yet, might be to replace the `shape` element that makes up the 'line' with a `bitmap` that has its gravity set towards the bottom. Just not sure whether the available tile modes would be able to yield the desired effect (repeat horizontally only).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that 1dp is less then one pixel on small screen sizes. Try to use 2dp or 1px for android:bottom.